# How to change default post attributes?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

My site needs to have image based posts, meaning the post is only an image.
Now i tried implementing it with Custom Post Types, but have encoutred problems,
like categories didn't show the right posts, pagination caused problems etc.

Now i thought to myself that i don't need the regular posts and if i could just edit them
to have only the featured image option enabled, life would be much easier.

But i failed to find any information regarding this.

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add featured image support/option simply add the following code snippet to your functions.php file located inside your theme's root folder

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
}
```

and to show the featured image inside your template you can do

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail(); // will show the featured image if you have set any for the post
}
```

Applicable to Wordpress version-2.9 and higher.

[image]

When you add new post just find the featured image meta box and set an featured image from there.

You can also setup image sizes (depending on that images will be displayed) at the front end, just take a look at [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size).